# Can I have 2 XBOX Live accounts from different countries on the same 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I live in Brazil and I have a XBOX 360. When I bought my 360, there was no Live in Brazil, so I signed up to XBOX Live US (lots of people do it here). I have two gold accounts, one is mine and one from my wife. Everything I buy (games, songs, DLC) is through pre-paid cards, and all under my account. Obviously I can use all bought content on her account too.

Now XBOX Live is available in Brazil, and they even provide a way to migrate your account from Live US keeping everything you bought. I don't want to migrate my account since because of brazilian laws not all games are available here. But since they are releasing more and more DLC with region lock, I thought about migrating only my wife's account so I can buy locked contend using her account.

My question is: can I keep two XBOX Live accounts from different countries (US and BR) in the same console, and will I be able to play content bought in one account with the other? My plan is to continue using my account to buy everything, and only use hers to buy content that is region locked (like the new Black Ops DLC, for example). But I want to be able to use all content on both accounts, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I have, on many occasions, had both my US account and my Canadian account on the same Xbox.

While it may seem strange that I would have both, after living in Canada for a number of years I became frustrated with the restrictions (I couldn't buy gamer points in Canada on my American account).  As a result I now have both.

This has worked seamlessly on both my American and (later) my Canadian Xbox.

While I can't be 100% sure about Brazil+US, I do know that Canada and US are separate regions and they do function as you would expect.

Comment: Do you happen to play Black Ops? I've read that Black Ops DLC is restricted to the region it was bought, which would mean that if you bought a DLC with the Canadian account you wouldn't be able to play with the US account. Did something similar ever happen to you?

Comment: Hmm.  While I suspect this answer is correct, US and Canada are treated as the same region most of the time.  XBox Live treats them as different, but 99% of games treat them as the same.  I would expect a lot of games to treat the US and Brazil differently, and a US game might not work with the Brazilian Live account (or vice versa) for that reason.

Comment: @Rodrigo I haven't purchased the Black Ops DLC, but I can try that tonight.  I have never bought DLC which differentiated between my accounts.  Then again, it's possible the game itself will differentiate (as US vs EU does).  However, the standard that groups Canada and the US together usually also groups SA and NA together.

Comment: My main concern is that the process is not reversible: once I migrate the account there's no turning back. So there's no way I could test it first...